# "It was from that moment where" vs. "it was from that moment when"

Tags: word-choice, when, where

> Now that I think about it, it was from
>   that moment where I started to have
>   doubts about him.

Would it be better to use the word "when" instead of "where," or are they both equally valid word choices? Is there any difference at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be:

> Now that I think about it, it was from that moment *that* I started to have doubts about him.

It sounds a bit awkward with all those *thats*, but "that" is grammatically correct. It might read better this way:

> Now that I think about it, that was the moment when I started to have doubts about him.

Or better yet:

> That was the moment when I started to doubt him.

I'm not sure if *where* or *when* would be incorrect grammatically speaking, but either would be confusingly redundant, as they serve essentially the same purpose as the prepositional phrase *from that moment* -- i.e., to specify a point in time. Thus, if I hear the sentence with either *when* or *where* in the place of *that*, it sets an expectation that it refers to **yet another point in time** at which something else happened after you started to have doubts, e.g.:

> ...it was from that moment *when* I started to have doubts about him *that I began trying to hack into his e-mail account to see if he was cheating*.

In short, if you use *when* or *where*, the thought feels unfinished to this American English speaker.

*That*, on the other hand, serves as a conjunction introducing the subordinate clause "I started to have doubts about him." Thus, it completes a thought.

Comment: ...In your second and third examples I would just leave out the "when" entirely. That's just my opinion.

Comment: Could I replace "Now that I think about it" with "If I think about it now?" Is using "when" or "where" grammatically incorrect?

Comment: @language hacker: Yes, replacing "now that..." with "if I..." is fine. I edited my answer to address grammaticality.

Comment: @kitukwfyer: Good idea!

Comment: You used "when" together with "that was the moment." Would it also be grammatically correct to say "it was from that moment when?"

Comment: Is "when" somehow better than "where", since when has to do with time, and where has to do with place, or is "where" just as valid as "when" here?

Comment: @language hacker: I would say *when* is a bit better than *where* because of the time implication, although *where* is sometimes used colloquially to indicate time. "It was from that moment when" would be correct when used as I used it in my last block quote above.